# Some crazy ideas that might help voting and make the "Thank you" reaction redundant

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, user-experience

I've been following the controversy around the introduction of the "Thank you" react, and one thing that stuck in my mind is that there is a perception that 1. Users don't upvote/accept enough, and 2. the thank you will be an additional road block. This got me thinking, why should people react positively to an answer, leave a comment, but fail to upvote?

### The UX design of voting doesn't mesh with social media

For better or worse, the vast majority of users (new and veteran alike) interact with social media regularly, and as such, we are subtly trained to expect things to appear in a way we are familiar with. Regardless of whether StackExchange *wants* to be in this space, it dominates the internet landscape. If you look at websites like Facebook, Twitter, Reddit, Instagram, etc. etc., there are some elements of convergent design in the user interface. In short, they have the content front and centre, and commenting **and voting** follows *immediately below* the post.

## The next thing happens below the content

[image]

If you look at what happens on a StackExchange page, it looks like the image below. What do you notice? It didn't occur to me immediately because I've been using SE for many years, but...

### I can't see how to vote when I'm done reading the post

In fact, the only thing that I can see for interacting with the post is a piece of text called "add a comment".

[image]

Now obviously as you become more familiar with the website, you start to learn the layout and can find the voting buttons, but for a brand new user (which as I understand is where the main issue arises) this is probably enough to stop me from voting. And I don't think this is a problem of new users *not wanting* to vote, how often do they click "add a comment and say something like...

[image]

This is from a new user who hasn't accepted the answer OR UPVOTED - at the time of screenshot, the vote tally for the answer was 0. And yet again, I can't see the upvote or accept buttons here. The (admittedly slightly contrived) full screen looks like this:

[image]

No voting in sight! I would even go so far as to say the act of needing to scroll back up to the top to vote once someone is done reading could subtly discourage *even regular users* from taking the effort to vote.

### Crazy Idea 1: put voting and accepting next to the "sign off badge"

Clearly even new users want to express gratitude for the effort someone has taken to answer their question. There's a little box down in the bottom right hand corner that identifies the answerer, and I would say I'm often more drawn to that as a measure of quality of answer than anything else - the reputation number adds weight to the opinion presented. Now imagine if the voting was next to the answerer. Not only would the upvote be much more connected to the person giving the answer, but you could even get *immediate feedback that your vote counted for something!* (If the users rep increased on clicking the button).

It could look something like this:

[image]

We could even add in an obvious little box under the user card designated for thanking the user directly. This could then hang around for (say) 10 days, and be deleted after that. This way the thanker gets to say thank you and *they are filtering out their comment themselves*. To stop users from using the thank you box for follow up comments, there could be some helpful text directing them to the comment box.

### Crazy Idea 2: Make the votes follow the user down

As for the vote tally for the given question/answer, keeping that at the top makes perfect sense. You want to get a quick idea of what the consensus on the quality of the post is before committing time to reading it, so it needs to be seen at the top. But again once you scroll down, the vote tally vanishes and you lose that little bit of feedback about the quality of the answer. So how could we fix that? Maybe with a follower..

[image]

This might be enough for the person reading the answer to remember to vote at all. The accept answer button could float down with the voting buttons as well.

### Crazy Idea 3: Descriptive buttons at the bottom

Another issue is that new users might not know what is expected of them with the voting system. And in fact, sometimes I even forget what it's for. Any user interface that requires you to refer to documentation to use it properly (especially when new users are involved) is not doing its job in my opinion. So, why make (new) users guess what the intent of features are and chastise them when they get it wrong? Why not *tell them specifically what is expected*? Give them descriptive buttons where they expect them that guide them in the way to use the site!

[image]

(**The exact text in the boxes is just a place-holder, the main idea is the buttons have some form of guiding description**) This method has the benefit that the dreaded comment box is hidden until it is needed/requested, and the point of the comment is made abundantly clear. These don't need to be permanent fixtures either, they can be "training wheels" that appear for new users until they get the hang of it.

### Thoughts and comments?

This all came to me last night while I was ruminating on what's special about SE and the problems it faces. But I freely admit I'm a lurker and not someone deeply involved in the community. Maybe these ideas have been posed before and shot down for various reasons that I don't know about. Either way, my point still stands, the voting system is at odds with the way (new) users are trained to expect voting to work through social media. SE is not meant to be social media, but why not lean into the way users have been trained elsewhere and leverage it in our own unique way, rather than working directly against it?

Comment: Consider what Crazy Idea 3 would look like on small display. Too much text and crowding on a touchscreen phone.

Comment: That's a good point. The buttons don't have to be obnoxiously large, just enough to get the point across. Obviously they can be implemented in a suitable way, it doesn't have to look like my slap dash hack job of an image :)

Comment: I don't think these ideas are anywhere near *crazy*, they all make sense to me. What I'd describe crazy is the stupid thanks reaction thing they rolled out a few weeks ago.

Comment: I like Crazy Idea 2!

Comment: "I would even go so far as to say the act of needing to scroll back up to the top to vote once someone is done reading could subtly discourage even regular users from taking the effort to vote." If I see a question long enough that voting requires scrolling back up, I am already primed to downvote it. This is a strong indication that the question is unfocused and/or has far too much code for a proper MRE.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That assumes a large display, no zoom, etc.  While _most_ questions I answer fit on my display (currently, the largest available MacBook Pro with the zoom for SO set to 110% due to some low-contrast/too-small text) without scrolling, it's _far_ from a rule.  As examples where I've answered and consider the questions to have fine MREs, none of [example 1](//stackoverflow.com/q/77312779/208273), [example 2](//stackoverflow.com/q/69385520/208273), and [example 3](//stackoverflow.com/q/68842160/208273) have the upvote arrow visible when the bottom of the question is barely onscreen.

Comment: That's also assuming that the user keeps as much of the question visible as possible: when my laptop is on a table (or my lap), if I want to look at the very bottom of the screen, I have to look down at a steep enough angle that it's not comfortable to remain in for a prolonged period.  Thus, if I'm reading something like this, I'll tend to scroll it higher on my screen where it's closer to straight-on.  And of course, this laptop on the larger end: plenty of people use smaller ones.

Comment: Really? It's not possible to demonstrate that problem (in example 1) without bringing in over a dozen dependencies using Gradle?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes and no. Yes, you could drop almost all of them and still get the same error.  However, if you don't already know why you're getting the error and just remove packages until you find the minimum set that produces that error message, then you will change the answer from "You need to extend `ComponentActivity`" to "You forgot to add a dependency on `androidx.activity:activity-compose`."  It's an important part of the question that the example from the documentation _even with all optional dependencies_ was hitting that issue.

Comment: It's also not an excessive number of dependencies by any means; with that few, I'd prefer that someone just give me the actual list rather than trying to minimize it, which could lead to a mistake and turn it into a less useful question.  I can easily check if the one dependency that matters is there or not.

Comment: I would argue that *once you know* that the problem isn't a missing dependency specification, the question should be edited to minimize the listing, or otherwise indicate that this isn't the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'd say it's at least _strongly hinted at_ by "(copied from Android docs)", since _generally_ the docs are correct, but this is now very off in the weeds. I linked _three_ questions to avoid a debate about the specifics of any one. My point is that it's not at all uncommon for properly minimized questions to result in the upvote arrow being offscreen once the user has finished reading them (especially given that a user may deliberately scroll _past_ the end of a question when reading it). Also, this issue isn't specific to questions; detailed answers would be similarly affected.

Answer (score 27):

Crazy idea 1 is right out. That's simply a no-go. It would make it look like votes are on the *user*, when they're not—they're on the *post* (i.e., the content).

Crazy idea 2 is actually quite reasonable. In fact, I have a userscript that makes the vote arrows (and everything else in that sidebar) "sticky", so that it follows down the viewport as I scroll the answer. This is particularly handy for long answers, so that I can vote on them accordingly after I finish reading them. I also find it useful when curating/moderating content: since the "close"/"delete" links are at the bottom, while the vote arrows are at the top, this saves a lot of scrolling when I want to both vote and close/delete a post.

If you want to try it out yourself, all that needs to be done is injecting the following style into the page's CSS:

```
/* Make voting arrows and other sidebar content "sticky", so that it scrolls with long posts. */
.js-voting-container {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

(The increased `z-index` ensures that the new, "Stacks"-style tooltips appear properly on top of the main content. Without this, the improperly-coded tooltips appear *behind* the text of the post.)

You can also install [this userscript](https://github.com/codygray/so-userscripts/blob/master/Prolix.user.js), but it does more than just this, and will be expanded over time according to my own whims, so *caveat emptor*.

Something like this has actually been proposed before, many years ago, as a new feature for the site. If I remember correctly, it was tried out, but ultimately the developers decided not to introduce it. I've been using this userscript for a while now, and I haven't found any real side effects. I would have no objection to introducing this as a first-class feature, although I don't have any real expectations that it will make any measurable difference to behavior. But that doesn't make it any less valuable as a way to save a couple of rolls of the scroll wheel.

Crazy idea 3—meh. I just don't buy this. Folks who have voting privileges should already know what the voting system means and how it works by that time. Besides, the voting system just isn't that complicated. An upvote means "I like this"; a downvote means "I dislike this". What could possibly be simpler? Now, yes, there are many *reasons* why you might like or dislike something: it does/doesn't show research effort, it is/isn't clear, it is/isn't useful, it is/isn't correct, etc. But those are all details, and something that is easily intuited as a "like"/"dislike" reaction. Adding more buttons here means more choices, and thus more friction. Adding more text means people are less likely to read it, and thus less likely to feel comfortable voting. It also means more clutter on the page for everyone else who already understands how the voting system works (which, as I already said, isn't that difficult or confusing, or even different from the rest of the Web). A final objection to this is that it veers dangerously close to [past suggestions that users need to provide a reason why they vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). With all of that considered, I'm more on the "no" side than the "meh" side for this particular suggestion.

Comment: Yeah I see your point about voting arrows next to the user - that could sway voting in other ways, people voting for users rather than answers. What about the separate thank you box? I think the idea of users self filtering their comments could cut down on work load significantly while letting people have their thank yous.
Like I mention, the descriptive boxes could be guiding the intention _in the place where users are when they are thinking about their reaction to the post_. They aren't more choices either, they are just repeating the same thing where people can see it

Comment: I also think the space at the end of a post looks plain barren. If I'm new and looking for the next interaction, the only thing I find is "share edit follow flag" which doesn't help much, and then I find "add a comment" and I'm like "Ah something familiar, I know what to do here". Again, the point is _new_ users are struggling. Experienced users don't have this issue

Comment: Another point that just occurred to me: The fact that you've hacked a way around the UI to make it more usable for yourself is a sign that something is missing!

Comment: @Phill That area is only barren until the post has been edited. After an edit has occurred, that big area in the middle contains the user card of the last editor (as well as the timestamp of the edit, and a link to see the whole revision history). Power users often hack around the site to make it more usable for them. A lot of what we do is weird, so a lot of my customizations would not necessarily be useful in general. But I agree that this one would be an improvement.

Comment: yeah, the area underneath isn't always barren. I guess one main point of my post is that the area underneath is under utilised... *insert "It's Free Real Estate" meme here*

Comment: @CodyGray Hmm. Your scrolling vote script scrolls the  votes behind the top nav bar for me :/

Comment: Additional problem with idea 1: it would introduce some weirdness with the responsive layout, as well as block the place the "edited by" box usually shows up in

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah, you must have the sticky top bar. I've turned that off so I can maximize the amount of screen space available to content. I haven't tested with that enabled at all.

Comment: @DavidPostill Easy enough to fix by bumping `top` from `0` to `50px` (or whatever size is appropriate for your display)

Comment: @manveti Thanks. I'll play with that later.

Comment: For maximum robustness, you would actually want to fetch the height of the top nav, and use that as the offset for `top`. (cc @DavidPostill)